# Converting a space seperated string to an array of pointers in C

Tags: c

I have a string like this: "arg1 arg2 arg3" that I want to send to exec.  But execvpe takes an array of pointers as the command arguments.  Is there a way that I can take arg1, arg2, and arg3 and put them into an array of pointers?

I've separated them with strtok, but not sure what to do next... I have *argv[x] waiting for them.

Thank you,
    J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtok` already hands you back pointers to each item, so all you need to do is take the values returned by `strtok` and place them in your `argv` array.

```
char *str = "arg1 arg2 arg3";
char *argv[3];

int i = 0;
argv[i] = strtok(args, " ");
while (argv[i] != NULL) {
    i++;
    argv[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
 }
```